# After upgrading to Vue 2.5 reflect.js.map is missing

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I upgraded my Vue 2.0 project to Vue 2.5, but now `Reflect.js.map` can't be found. The project still works without the .map file but how can I get rid of the error? I have enabled sourcemaps in tsconfig.json, but that's probably just for .ts files. I'm not sure how to enable/disable this in webpack.config.json.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)


http://localhost/../project/dist/Reflect.js.map
```

tsconfig.json

```
"sourceMap": true
```

webpack.config.json

```
entry: './src/index.ts',
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
devtool: "source-map", 
module: {..}
```

Comment: thats one problem with npm try reinstalling it back or use yarn to install

Comment: I have deleted the entire `node_modules` folder and done `npm install` but the problem persists.